# How do I align a Tikzpicture with a matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, alignment

The following code

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

...

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subfigure[sub-title 1]
{\label{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[black,ultra thick, scale=0.5]
\draw (1,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle; 
\draw (3,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=blue!20!white, draw=black] (1,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle; 
\filldraw[fill=white!100!white, draw=black] (3,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
\draw[step=1cm,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (5,5); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\qquad\qquad
$
\begin{matrix}
{\longrightarrow} \\
\quad \\
\quad \\
\quad \\
\quad \\
\end{matrix}
$
\qquad\qquad
\subfigure[sub-title 2]
{\label{}
$
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$
}
\caption{Main title}
\end{figure}
```

yields the picture
[image]

How can I align both subfigures on the same horizontal line? I would prefer not to switch to using different packages as I have many figures already created. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable example if possible, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}cp{0.3\textwidth}}
            \vspace*{-1.5cm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[black,ultra thick, scale=0.5]
                \draw (1,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle; 
                \draw (3,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
                \filldraw[fill=blue!20!white, draw=black] (1,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,4) -- (1,4) -- (1,5) -- (0,5) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle; 
                \filldraw[fill=white!100!white, draw=black] (3,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
                \draw[step=1cm,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (5,5); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    & $\longrightarrow$&
    
            \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
        $   \begin{pmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
                1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
                1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
                0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
            \end{pmatrix} $
            \\
    \center{(a)}
    &&
    \center{(b)}
\end{tabular}
        \caption{Main title}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Thank you.

Comment: You can now mark for accepted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With use of `subfloat` (as is defined in `subcaption` version 1.3) and `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf,
            singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize,
                         singlelinecheck}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\subfloat[sub-title 1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.42]
    \filldraw[fill=blue!20!white, semithick] 
        (0,1) |- (1,5) |- (5,4) |- (1,0) |- cycle;
    \filldraw[fill=white!100!white, semithick] 
        (3,1) |- (4,3) |- cycle;
    \draw[step=1cm,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
                    }
    \raisebox{10mm}{\quad$\longrightarrow$\quad}
    \subfloat[sub-title 1]{$\begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
                    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
                    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
                    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
                            \end{pmatrix}$
                          }
\caption{Main title}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For referencing of figure and subfigures you need to add labels to their captions.

Comment: This also looks a great option, but I get a Latex error saying that I cannot use the Subfigure package with the Subcaption package. This may be a limitation of the style files that I have to load for the journal I am submitting my paper to. Thanks.

Comment: @Marcus, sorry, but in your question is not any information, which package you use and which one is not desired. As now I see, your question is very unclear.

Comment: I am submitting a paper to an MDPI journal which by default loads the following packages: fontenc, inputenc, calc, indentfirst, fancyhdr, graphicx, epstopdf, lastpage, ifthen, lineno, float, amsmath, setspace, enumitem, mathpazo, booktabs, titlesec, etoolbox, tabto, xcolor, soul, multirow, microtype, tikz, totcount, changepage, paracol, attrib, upgreek, cleveref, amsthm, hyphenat, natbib, hyperref, footmisc, url, geometry, newfloat, caption. I also load the packages: tkz-tab, and subfigure. I wish to use the subfigure package, but I guess I cannot use the subcaption package.

Comment: why yo use obsolete package `subfigure`?

Comment: Because I wasn't aware it was obsolete. What should I be using instead?

Comment: `subcaption` for example. But this will not solve your problem if you will still use `multicolumns`.

Comment: I do not use multicolumns. If you can provide Latex code for what I want to do using the subcaption package that would be great. Although the solution by Raffaele works, it is not ideal because (as you point out) I need to have labels for the captions (which are not possible with his workaround). Thank you.

Comment: I can after then you provide me MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which mimic your document and reproduce your problem.

Comment: That's kind of you. But I realize now that this is an issue that the journal concerned needs to address. Also, a MWE would require me to send you the journal style files. So in the meantime I'll go with the approach that Raffaele outlined, and let the journal deal with it if they don't like it.